# How to change default 'dotnet' command to .NET 5?

Tags: .net, ubuntu

I have both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 on my ubuntu, and wondering If i can change 'dotnet' command to run .NET 5 instead .Net Core 3.1. Now to execute .NET 5 commands I use 'dotnet-sdk.dotnet' command.

```
dotnet --list-sdks

3.1.404 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

and

```
dotnet-sdk.dotnet --list-sdks

5.0.100 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/105/sdk]
```

Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: It looks like you've installed .NET in two different ways - one using a snap and one not. If you install .NET 5 with the Ubuntu package manager instead of using a snap, I'd expect it to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alias should meet your requirement in this instance:

```
alias dotnet="dotnet-sdk.dotnet"
```

To then make the changes persistent across terminal sessions, add the line to ~/.bashrc

Then if you ever need to use the original dotnet version, you can then do:

```
\dotnet
```